# Given this string (with '\n') how can I strip it from all the returns?

Tags: c#, string

Here's the string:

```
\n\n\t\thttp://www.linkedin.com/in/ckenworthy\n\n\t
```

How can I strip everything so I only end up with:

```
http://www.linkedin.com/in/ckenworthy
```

I've tried the following:

```
string value = doc.XPathSelectElement("/ipb/profile/contactinformation/contact[title/text() = 'LinkedIn']/value").Value;
                value = value.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "");
                return value;
```

But I always end up with the first line I posted up there. Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`value.Trim()` will probably do exactly what you want. It will remove all whitespace characters from the start and end of the string.

The reason `Environment.NewLine` may not work is because its value depends on whether you're running on Windows, Unix or Mac, but that really doesn't matter if you're getting the string from a remote system - the remote system will still return the same newline separator (`'\n'` in this case).

Answer (score 3):

Try...

```
value.Trim()
```